# Drupal User: UID argument with CCK field in URL

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, cck

I have a view limiting nodes created by a specific users via User: UID argument. The views page path settings are page/% which takes the string username or UID from the argument (e.g., page/15 displays content created by user 15). Although the functionality is perfect I would like to use a CCK text field, from the users content profile, to populate the % in page/%.

So, does anyone know how to keep the functionality of the existing argument but change the display URL from UID to a CCK value?

Simply put I want to filter content based on UID but have views construct the URL with a CCK value.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the https://drupal.org/project/pathauto module.

Comment: The path auto module works great however, for dynamic URLs constructed using arguments it doesn't jive.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple. Add a **Contextual Filter** of that field and it is ready.

Notice that this field should be something like a non space text or a digital number or generally a text that will be rendered without problems in the url path. It must also be unique otherwise you may have more than one results.